# Measure heart rate variability with iphone camera lens

Tags: ios, camera, heartbeat

There are several apps on `AppStore`, like `Stress Check` by Azumio, which calculate heart rate variability using an iphone camera (by placing your finger on the camera lens), and a few others offering  only measurement of bpm the same way. I'm looking for an algorithm to implement this functionality in my iOS App, or better for some sample code (not necessarily Objective-C code).

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Grab image frame from camera
2. Compare image metrics of frame to previous frame.  You need to figure out what metrics to use: brightness, color, etc.
3. If metrics are significantly different in one direction, then you have a heartbeat.
4. Pause some indeterminate amount of time.
5. Go to 1

Comment: Has anyone worked out this algorithm? Sample project / code?